# Stored procedure OUT as CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Below is my Stored Procedure ( Oracle ). Currently, RET_RESULT OUT is VARCHAR2. Someone suggested me to use CLOB instead of VARCHAR2. Can you help how to use RET_RESULT CLOB as OUT in my procedure. I have to return result with comma delimited values.

I read on net and found DBMS_LOB.write and append. But not sure how to use them here.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE_DIV
( 
  CALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2, 
  XCALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2, 
  RET_RESULT OUT VARCHAR2,
)

AS
......

BEGIN

......
 RET_RESULT := var_g ||','|| var_c ||','|| var_r ;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this as:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE_DIV
( 
  CALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2, 
  XCALL_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2, 
  RET_RESULT OUT CLOB,
)
AS
......

BEGIN

......
 RET_RESULT := EMPTY_CLOB() || var_g ||','|| var_c ||','|| var_r ;

END;
```

Comment: Can you please explain this. What is EMPTY_CLOB()  ?

Comment: My java code will parse this RET_RESULT. If you add empty_clob ( comma separated empty value I guess ) then var_g will be on index 2

Comment: You should use dbms_lob.append instead of ||. And also dbms_lob.createtemporary.

Comment: @ ibre5041 : Can you please explain why and how to use

Comment: @VJS . . . The `||` is fine.  It is documented specifically to work with CLOBs as well as characters (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm).  I find it easier to use because when I've done such conversions, my code is often filled with `||`.